# ffmpeg last frame freezes, audio keeps playing

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, video-encoding, quicktime

I'm using fffmpeg to cut an H.264 video into specific shots. I need it to be frame accurate, which isnt a problem if I only encode video (now that I know how to calculate the ms from the number of frames). But if I add audio, when playing back on Quicktime Player or VLC, it freezes on the last frame and then keeps playing the audio for about another second. I added "-shortest" to make the audio stream cut-off when the video does, but to no avail (didn't seem to have an effect).

Here's my complete ffmpeg entry:

```bash
ffmpeg -ss 51411ms -i 'input.mov' -frames:v 150 -shortest -y 'output.mov'
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: have you tried using `-t 5s` instead of `-frames:v`? I'm assuming 30fps so 150 frames is 5s

Comment: That did it! Amazing, thank you very much Jaromanda... problem solved!